# Как проверить рандом на последовательность цифр?

Tags: c#

Нужно узнавать, когда рандомайзер видал три одинаковых последовательных числа

0,0,0 или 1,1,1

```
int RandomIndex = Random.Range(0,2);
```

**UPD:**
придумал такой вариант для одного числа, но почему-то не работает

```
    List<int> teams = new List<int>();

    int RandomIndex = Random.Range(0,2);
    if(RandomIndex == 0) {
        teams.Add(RandomIndex);
        if (teams.Count == 3){
            Debug.Log("Последовательность 3-х чисел 0 найдена!");
            teams.Clear();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Вам придется хранить, как минимум, 2 предыдущих значения. В чем, собственно, проблема-то?

Comment: Вам нужно создать [скользящее окно на три последних значения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/347378/) и проверять, что в окне все три цифры одинаковы. Сделайте для начала класс-обёртку который выдаёт по запросу рандом наружу, а сам заталкивает последнее значение во внутреннее хранилище трёх последних цифр.

Comment: Я не понимаю, как вам нужно упаковать эту задачу в нужный вид. Допустим. есть некоторый бесконечный Enumerable<int> из которого вы берёте Take(9) значений. Вам достаточно будет в цикле пройтись по этой выборке и дампить значения, вставляя по необходимости вывод строки "обнаружено три одинаковых значения: (1)"?

Comment: А если 4 ноля подряд, 1 или 2 раза надо оповещать?

Comment: да если можно, было бы хорошо)

Comment: @KillNoise что не устраивает в моем ответе?

Comment: @dgzargo, Он ждет ответ с адским Linq-однострочником

Comment: @AK не обязательно хранить сами последние цифры, можно хранить пару `(последнее число, количество повторений)`. И алгоритм проверки будет быстрее, и количество памяти меньше. Так же будет работать с большими повторениями как в вопросе Андрея NOP.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, такой ответ уже опубликован

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин спасибо! хоть ты поддерживаешь мою версию!)

Comment: Да, точно (+)..

Answer (score 4):

```
Random random = new Random();
int cur = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int t = random.Next(0, 2);

    if (t == cur) count++;
    else
    {
        cur = t;
        count = 1;
    }

    if (count == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"последовательность из 3-х {t} найдена!");
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

> последовательность из 3-х 1 найдена!
>   последовательность из 3-х 0 найдена!
>   последовательность из 3-х 0 найдена!

изначально ставлю количество в "0" а текущее значение - не важно
после получение случайного числа, проверяю, сохраняется ли последовательность
если последовательность уже нужной длины - сообщаю об этом

если нужно чтобы алгоритм информировал "2 раза при 4-ех одинаковых числах" - заменить часть кода на это:

```
    if (count >= 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"последовательность из 3-х {t} найдена!");
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"последовательность из {count}-х {t} найдена!");` во втором варианте

Comment: Решение неуниверсально. Если вдруг мы захотим искать тройки `1, 0, 1` или вообще, генератор выдает числа от 0 до 9, а мы хотим искать тройки `5, 6, 7` или `9, 6, 3`. Ну это так, просто к сведению для потомков. В первом приближении это именно то решение, которое решает данную конкретную задачу.

Answer (score 4):

Ну что ж, этот вопрос не должен оставаться без Linq-решения!

Подключим пакет `MoreLinq` или просто скопируем из него код метода [`Windowed`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Windowed.cs)

Напишем метод, выдающий последовательность случайных чисел:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RndSeq()
{
    var random = new Random();
    while (true) yield return random.Next(2);
}
```

Используем его:

```
var seq = // Из последовательности
    RndSeq() // случайных чисел
    .Take(100) // взять 100 первых
    .Windowed(3) // применить к ним оконную функцию с шириной окна в 3 элемента
    .Where(triple => triple.Distinct().Count() == 1) // где все три элемента одинаковые
    .Select(triple => triple.First()); // взять из этих трех первый
foreach (var n in seq)
    Console.WriteLine("Найдена тройка из " + n);
```

Вместо `triple.Distinct().Count() == 1` в данном частном случае случае можно использовать `(new[] { 0, 3 }).Contains(triple.Sum())`, т.е. считаем сумму элементов в тройке и выбираем те тройки, сумма которых равна 0 или 3. Это должно работать немного быстрее.

В более общем случае, возможно, стоит иметь коллекцию паттернов:

```
var patterns = new[]
{
    new[] { 0, 0, 0 },
    new[] { 1, 1, 1 },
};
```

Тогда, код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var seq =
    RndSeq()
    .Take(100)
    .Windowed(3)
    .Where(triple => patterns.Any(p => p.SequenceEqual(triple)));
foreach (var t in seq)
    Console.WriteLine("Найдена тройка { " + string.Join(", ", t) + " }");
```

Answer (score 3):

И ещё одна версия, не без linq, но на итераторы (что-то меня в последнее время тянет в эту сторону).

Попробуем решить задачу в более общем виде и заодно реализуем [скользящее окно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/347378/).

Положим, у нас есть некоторый бесконечный IEnumerable, в частности, это может быть ряд случайных чисел как у топикстартера, но может быть и каким угодно рядом бесконечных чисел. Ок, реализуем не сильно заморачиваясь с имплементацией IEnumerable и IEnumerator через yield:

```
// Создаём бесконечный IEnumerable<int> от MinVal до MaxVal
public class Rnd
{
    public Rnd(Random random, int min, int max)
    {
        RandomGenerator = random;
        MinVal = min;
        MaxVal = max;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetRandomSequence()
    {
        while(true)
            yield return RandomGenerator.Next(MinVal, MaxVal);
    }

    private Random RandomGenerator { get; set; }
    private int MinVal { get; set; }
    private int MaxVal { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и поскольку бесконечный ряд нам не нужен - мы будем брать из него несколько первых значений (для наглядности прибито .Array() гвоздями):

```
int seed = 0;
var generator= new Random(seed);
var rnd = new Rnd(generator, 0, 2);
var sample = rnd.GetRandomSequence().Take(9).ToArray();
```

Далее мы попробуем сделать некоторый класс скользящего окна (реализую в первый раз, поэтому идеи/замечания вэлком):

```
public class SlidingWindow
{
    public SlidingWindow(int size)
    {
        Data = new int[size];
        WindowSize = size;
        ResetWindow();
    }

    public void PushNext(int value)
    {
        Data = Data.Skip(WindowSize -1).Concat(Data.Take(WindowSize -1)).ToArray();
        Data[WindowSize-1] = value;

        if(CurrentItem != 0)
            CurrentItem--;
    }

    public void ResetWindow()
    {
        CurrentItem = WindowSize;
    }

    public bool IsWindowFull()
    {
        return CurrentItem == 0;
    }

    public int[] GetWindow()
    {
        if (!IsWindowFull())
            return new int[] {}; // или может кинуть исключение?

        return Data;
    }

    private int[] Data { get; set; }
    private int WindowSize { get; set; }
    private int CurrentItem { get; set; }
}
```

В принципе, ничего сложного, но один момент любопытен: как сдвигается по кругу массив. Вот ещё раз, помедленнее:

```
int[] m = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
m.Skip(3).Concat(m.Take(3)).ToArray().Dump();
```

Выведет: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3

(Мы же могли это сделать в цикле, но нам надо больше <s>минералов</s> linq!)

Ну и собственно итерируем:

```
// Итерируем исходную последновательность
public IEnumerable<int> MyCustomIter(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    var window = new SlidingWindow(3);

    var a = source.GetEnumerator();

    while (a.MoveNext())
    {
        var b = a.Current;
        window.PushNext(b);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        if(window.IsWindowFull())
        {
            var snapshot = window.GetWindow();
            var firstElem = snapshot[0];
            if(snapshot.All(x => x == firstElem))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Подряд три элемента: {firstElem}");
            }
        }
        yield return b;
    }
}
```

При этом мы тут навставляли разных умных конструкций <s>вместо банального for, чтобы вы ничего не поняли</s> так как помним, что IEnumerable может быть и бесконечным, а не прибит через .ToArray() к конечной последовательности.

Запускаем:

```
var result = MyCustomIter(sample);
result.Dump();
```

Собственно, вывод будет как и заказывали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]